# How to resolve Firefox browser loading issue with Webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, browser-automation

When I run web driver with Firefox browser it generates a blank Firefox browser and after a minute the browser closes without running the WebDriver  program. The following error is generated on eclipse:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Please how do I resolve this. I am using the latest Firefox browser (47.0.1), and selenium java client driver 2.53.0.

Comment: your firefox browser and java webdriver version is too high,and not match each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Firefox to `47.0.1` and Selenium Java client to `2.53.1`

Comment: why? do these versions include a bug fix?

Comment: Latest version of Firefox has some compatibility issues with the older version of Selenium, but it is working fine with latest version of Selenium

Comment: See [Bug Details](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1851)

Comment: Thats great! Could you add that into your answer so it is more "complete" for future visitors to the site asking the same question

Comment: @ curious I updated my selenium java client from 2.53.0 to 2.53.1 and the issue has been resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can't run my test script even using selenium 2.53.1 and firefox 47.0.1

Answer (score 0):

As of v2.51.0, the firefox driver supports Firefox 44, so without posting any code that's about all I can help you with.

[Source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG)